# Not able to access environment variables in bash scripts

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have previously set some environment variables of my own like `export EDITOR="vim"` in my `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Also I have showmessage script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

notify-send -t 50000 -u normal "editor is: $EDITOR"
```

When I run the script in the terminal by `"~/scripts/showmessage"` everything is fine and I get the desired output, i.e. "editor is: vim".

But when I call/run the script through keybindings like Mod+t it can't get the `$EDITOR` value and gives me "editor is: ".

Comment: Add output of `declare -p EDITOR` from your interactive shell to your question (no comment).

Comment: The output is:
`declare -x EDITOR="vim"`

Comment: I have set it in /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: Try to move your variable assignment to `~/.bash_profile` (personal initialization file, executed for login shells).

Comment: I did so but still no luck even rebooting didn't help

Comment: Then, from my point of view, all that remains is to insert it into `/etc/profile`: `EDITOR="vim"; export EDITOR` Be careful. Errors in `/etc/profile` (systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells) can cause you to lock yourself out.

Comment: Setting it in ~/.profile and /etc/profile did the job.
Much appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe you can remove it from `/etc/profile`.

Comment: That's right. I just kept the one in home.